# How to enable gzip compression for PHP-generated pages?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
# Insert filter on all content
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

And all my static content returns Content-Encoding: gzip. But my PHP-generated pages doesn't and GTmetrix site says that I need to compress this content (my web-pages). How to enable gzip for PHP -generated pages?
I have the same .htaccess settings in another project and web-pages compression works on it.

My site uses Magento 2 engine.

Comment: This should work for PHP as well just make sure you're setting your headers to the correct content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in shared hosting settings. I contacted the support and they enabled compression for pages.